# .indexOf() within a loop

Tags: javascript

I have a for loop that allows you to see the existence of a character in strings

```
for (var int = 0; int <length; int++) {
     console.log(name[int].indexOf('z') >= 0);
}
```

the problem that my code stops after the first iteration, I want to know where is the problem

Comment: what are you setting length to?

Comment: probably name[0] is null...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing `name` when checking for `length`:

```
or (var int = 0; int < name.length; int++)
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Don't take the `int` as a variable name change the name of variable.
2. what is the `length` here?
3. don't use the `length` as a variable name because length is the reserve in javascript.

Do that all and then try.

Comment: here is my code 

    for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
         console.log(name[i].indexOf('z') >= 0);
    }

if I try to display just name[i] it works, but if I add .indexOf() the problem appeared

Comment: @MzoughiYahya as I can understand you want the index of text if your name variable is an input type then use: `name[i].value.indexOf('z')` and if name variable is a html element then use `name[i].innerHTML.indexOf('z')`.

Comment: @BrokenHeartღ The OP's code is working good [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/tKr9y/)

Comment: @user1671639 I am not to see that its working and how can you assume that name is a text. and if name is a text then there will no need of loop.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing to mention the string to be checked.

```
for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
     console.log(name[i].indexOf('z') >= 0);
}
```

Don't use `int` as variableName, it causes me a bit of confusion when looking at your code.

Comment: @MzoughiYahya variable names like "int" is quite unusual.  It will confusion to reader.  **Readability is main concept in Software Development**.

Comment: @MzoughiYahya Check this [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/tKr9y/)

Answer (score 1):

Why you need indexOf? I don't understand. And don't use `int` for variable name. As for the for loop it should be `name.length`

```
for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
 console.log(name[i] === "z");
}
```